# Как положить в Map key номер строки?

Tags: java

Нужно считать данные из файла в Map, ключом которой является номер строки файла, а value - это текст в строке файла.

Исходный файл примерно такой:

```
BMW  
Lambo  
Giguli  
BLA  
Lada  
Car
```

Не могу разобрать как положить в Map key - номер строки!

Comment: Свое что-то есть уже или код надо польностью за Вас написать?

Comment: а как текст читаете?

Comment: String filePath = path;
HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap();
String s;
int i = 0;
while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) 
    map.put(++i, s);
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное:)

Answer (score 2):

```
Map<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<Integer,String>();

map.put(nomer_stroki, sama_stroka);
```

Comment: Если бы у меня  изначально была нумерация в файле , вопрос не возникло бы. для меня не понятно когда при считывание файла он заносил в MAp номер строки (key).  на данный момент данный которые в файле я закидываю в Map!  Спасибо Вам за ответ. Я начинающий в java ,, так если что не так , простите!

Comment: @Wafe, так покажите как вы считываете строку

Comment: @Wafe просто заведите счетчик (int) и увеличивайте его при чтении каждой строки из файла.

Comment: Уже так и сделал:) Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

В вашей задаче использование Map кажется избыточным. Достаточно ведь завести обычный массив(если известно количество строк в файле) или `ArrayList`

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("filename")));
ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
for(String s = reader.readLine(); s != null; s = reader.readLine()){
    strings.add(s);
}
```

Всё, далее по номеру строки получаете саму строку за константное время.

Comment: Мне нужно именно  через Map мне дальше нужно с ключами работать. Спасибо вам:)

Comment: @Wafe, я не очень представляю для чего это может быть нужно. Строки в файле пронумерованы в естесственном порядке, выходит что целочисленные индексы в массиве будут работать аналогично целочисленным ключам в Map. Разве что это учебная задача и в задании сказано использовать именно Map.

Comment: `@iksuy`
Это не совсем учебное задание. Но реализовать нужно! Спасибо вам за проявленный интерес и за ваш ответ. Thanks:)